# IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5 - UTF-8 encoding error on console despite setting the encoding type

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, intellij-idea-2018

As the title clearly describes, some `UTF-8` characters such as (`ğ`, `ç`, `ş`, etc.) could not be displayed on the console output despite (1) setting all the encoding preferences available in the **Settings** UI to `UTF-8`, and (2) adding the `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` parameter to the `idea64.exe.vmoptions` file as it is provided in [another question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695918/intellij-idea-console-issue).

**IntelliJ IDEA Version:** `2018.3.5 (Ultimate Edition)`

Edit: I am running my **web app** in **debug** mode, and using `Apache Tomcat` as the servlet container. So, the console output is the log of the web app.

Comment: Could you please describe how exactly you're running your application from the IDE, and attach a screenshot of the console?

Comment: Please, see the updated post. @yole

Comment: `and (2) adding the -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 parameter to the idea64.exe.vmoptions file` do not open file manually, use Help | Edit Custom VM Options... action, edit the file and restart IDE. Try also adding `-Dfile.encoding` to VM Options of the Run/Debug Configuration you use to launch the server. If this is the log file, make also sure that the characters are written correctly by opening this file from some other text editor.

Answer (score 2):

As @Andrey stated, if you want to see those symbols in Run/Debug console you should add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` VM option to your Run/Debug Configuration, not to IDE options.

Answer (score 0):

183.5153.38 version is an example.

Your IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate runs AppData \ Local \ JetBrains \ Toolbox \ apps \ IDEA-U \ ch-0 \ 183.5153.38 \ bin \ idea.exe.

- In the 183.5153.38.vmoptions file, add 'Dfile.encoding = UTF-8'